# Problems with create internal links( Anchor links) on a blog post in Blogger?

Tags: html, blogger

6:23 AM (1 hour ago)

Hi, can anybody help to understand how to create Internal links (Anchor Links) in a post? I can't able to find any helpful answer. Feeling very frustrated.

I did exactly what a person said me on the Blogger product forum -

For anchor link:
You can create hyperlink in the HTML mode. Just insert the following code where you want to place an anchor. (you can change archorlinkname to whatever you like)

```
<a name="anchorlinkname"></a>
```

For the link within the same post that you want to jump to that anchor, please use this code. (you can also change the word in yellow)

```
<a href="#anchorlinkname">Click here to go to anchorlinkname</a>
```

But something weird is happening once I am updating my post or going from HTML mode to Compose mode.

Error -

```
<a href="https://www.blogger.com/blogger.g?blogID=48019486#overview">


<a href="https://www.blogger.com/null" name="overview"></a>
```

I don't know why these https://blogger.com/blogger.g?blogID=48 and  https://blogger.com/null gets added automatically. It redirecting me back to the admin post section or to blogger sign in section if I am not Signed In.

My Blog - www.lifewithdata.com

Comment: Try to write like this `<a href='/#anchor'>links</a>` adding full url its better `<a href="https://yoursite.com/#anchor">links</a>`..

Comment: I did it but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/blogger/5MU_HH5T7rA

you must add the address of the page or post.

only works in the non-dynamic templates.

Comment: But, I have a Dynamic template. Do you know any other way to do it? I tried it but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Peace be upon those who follow guidance, I was able to make internal links within post on **blogspot** platform by using anchors like below:

```
<a href="Your-Post-Permalink#sectionName">sectionName</a>
<a name="sectionName">sectionName</a>
```

[image]

I was using a theme based on **Dynamic Views** and worked for me, and changed it to other [theme](https://ourcms.blogspot.com/2019/08/adding-member-login-page-to-umbraco-site.html) and the links still work.